# Mysql unix_timestamp with date_add does not give correct timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to a get a unix_timestamp after doing a date_add to my database field but it still giving me the unix_timestamp of the original value not after the date_add.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT data1.speed,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date_Add(data1.dateTimer , Interval '+08:00' hour_minute)) as dateTimer
```

For example the dateTimer value is 2015-10-02 15:27:53 after date_add is 2015-10-02 23:27:53 but the unix_timestamp is giving me 1443799673 which refers to 2015-10-02 15:27:53. I even tried the CONVERT_TZ function its still the same.

Comment: Did you try `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date_Add(data1.dateTimer , Interval '+08:00' hour_minute))` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data1.dateTimer)`? They should be different.

Comment: I have tried and both having same value. I read some other articles say there is a bug in mysql but mine is version: 5.1.73

Comment: Why don't you try to create a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` of the date value, and add `8 * 60 * 60 = 28800` seconds to the result, if it is really a bug?

Comment: Yes I am thinking on that line the problem the interval I keep in session value as string in this format +08:00 etc. So what is the best way to convert any of the timeZoneOffset into the hour?

Comment: You have two options: Parse the timezone string, and doing the calculations to get the number of seconds in the offset. You can also put the date into a `DateTime` object, and convert the timezone automatically by setting the default timezone and then changing the timezone of the object (see http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

Comment: I dont get your second option well. Can I do that DateTime object within the mysql query or do it separately ?

Comment: I'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer covers the case when the situation you describe is affected by a bug.

You have two options:

1. Parse the timezone information. Make sure it is always in the same format. For the case above (`+08:00`) you can use something like `($tz[0] == '+' ? 1 : (-1)) * (3600 * substr($tz, 1, 2) + 60 * substr($tz, 3, 2))`. Here `$tz` is your timezone information.
   Add this number of seconds to the timestamp of your data.
2. Parse the timestamp using a `DateTime` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). This can be done when given a string of the format `2015-10-03 19:52:06`. Set the timezone to your current timezone ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)). Then, modify the timezone with the users timezone (using [setTimezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)).

Comment: Ok I take option one. Is this the first thing you do $tz="+08:00"? The rest I understand. I think the second option is more efficient but I dont know where to apply is it in the query itself or when I run my while loop ?

Comment: Yes that I have tested I dont know  how to test your second method. Any further example how to put the tz value in it ?